# Is there a way to bring content files into views with white space removed?

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to have the title in a view, once as the first letter, once as full title, and then have Drupal group these fields, as follows.

> A
> Alabama
> Alaska
> Arizona

> C
> California
> Connecticut

However, when someone enters content as " Alabama" with a space as first character, I get this.

> Alabama
> A
> Alaska
> Arizona

> C
> California
> Connecticut

I have tried removing the white space in the field settings, I tried using `trim($output)` on the view template.

Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: translitaration module

Comment: White space? CSS? Who enters what where?

Comment: Did you try 'Rewrite Results' option in the views field where you can remove whitespaces.

Comment: I did try that.  It will remove the white space sort the titles under the correct letter but then  the sort criteria is still using the white space.   So, say  " California" has an extra space, then sort will have C, then A, then B.

Comment: Sorry, I mean space.   The title of a node is entered with a space in the beginning of the title.  So " Alabama" instead of "Alabama"

Comment: Why not remove the white space from the beginning of the titles on the content. I.e. resave them with no leading space (and make sure there can't be a leading space in the future). That would solve the problem, right?

Comment: How is the data 'entered'? Are they nodes? Taxonomy terms? A field attached to an entity?